# I want to remove files from object

Tags: javascript, html

I created a multiple file upload form. And it shows me the list of files I'm about to upload once I've selected the files. and i made delete file button to remove files that have been deleted from the object but cannot be deleted

```
<input type="file" class="" id="fileInput" multiple onchange="displayFiles()" style="width: 85px">
```

```
function removeFile(index) {
  var input = document.getElementById("fileInput");
  Array.from(input.files).splice(index, 1);
  displayFiles();
}
```

I tried this method and it didn't work.

```
function removeFile(index) {
  var input = document.getElementById("fileInput");
  delete input.files[index];
  displayFiles();
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this small example helps, you could create an array of indices to skip which are used when uploading.

```js
const get = str => document.querySelector(str);

get("#myFiles").addEventListener("change", e => {
  get("#howMany").setAttribute("max", e.target.files.length);
});

get("#upload").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const files = get("#myFiles").files;
  const len = get("#howMany").value;
  const data = new FormData();
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const targetFile = files[i];
    data.append("files[]", targetFile, targetFile.name);
  }
  devFetch("testurl", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data
  });
});

/* DEV FETCH EMULATE NORMAL FETCH FOR STACK SNIPPET, SHOULD JUST BE FETCH */
function devFetch(url, options) {
  console.log("Posting to", url, "with method", options.method);
  console.log("Body:");
  console.log(options.body.getAll("files[]"));
}
```

```html
<input id="myFiles" type="file" multiple /> <br />
<input id="howMany" type="range" min=0 max=0 /> <br />
<button id="upload">upload</button>
```